# bash/sed script to get output from a file using a regex

Tags: regex, bash, file-io, sed

I have a file which contains lines of the form `object 0: data: 2`, `object 0: data: 232132` in between other lines in the file.
I need to extract the `data` values from the file for all `object i` and store them space separate in a output file say `output` using `bash` or `sed`.
It would great if someone can help me in achieving this.

**Example input**:

```
num objects: 3
object    0: name: 'x'
object    0: size: 4
object    0: data: 1
object    1: name: 'y'
object    1: size: 4
object    1: data: 3231
object    2: name: 'x'
object    2: size: 4
object    3: data: -32
```

**Example output:**

```
1 3231 -32
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
awk '$3=="data:"{print $4}' file
```

This outputs the 4th field when the 3rd field is equal to "data:".

Shorter still, you could just match the pattern `/data:/`:

```
awk '/data:/{print $4}' file
```

To output the numbers on the same line, use `printf` rather than `print`. To keep things cleaner, you can use an array and print the values in the `END` block:

```
awk '/data:/{a[++n]=$4}END{for(i=1;i<=n;++i)printf "%s%s",$4,(i<n?FS:RS)}' file
```

Using an array like this makes it easy to separate each value with a space `FS` and add a newline `RS` at the end.

Any of these commands can produce an output file using redirection `> output`.

Comment: just add **| tr "\n" " "** to all commands above and I get all values space separated..thanks :)

Comment: @piXel_pRo yeah, you can do that if you want, although it's nice to avoid using more tools than necessary. I would've suggested simply doing `awk '/data:/{printf "%s ",$4}' file`, although this results in there being no newline at the end of the output.